# Subquery in order by in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, subquery, flask-sqlalchemy

I need some help in sqlalchemy query.
I'm having trouble implementing this mysql query in sqlalchemy.

MySQL Query:

```
select u.post_id
from
    user_record_cards u
where
    u.record_card_id = 1 and u.count = 1
order by (select 
        count(*)
    from
        post_likes p
    where
        p.post = u.post_id)
```

My sqlalchemy query is:

```
obj = (
    UserRecordCard.query
    .filter(
        UserRecordCard.record_card_id == 1,
        UserRecordCard.count == 1
    ).order_by(
        Like.query.filter(
            Like.post == UserRecordCard.post_id
        ).count()
    ).all()
)
```

and my Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 3453, in _literal_as_text
    "SQL expression object or string expected."
ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- what help do you need?  Show the code, the output you're getting, and the output you want.

Comment: @Prune now i added my sqlalchemy and traceback!,hope it helps!

Comment: We're getting there; what line of *your* code is the problem, then?  What have you tried to simplify your code to separate the problem point from the good parts?  I'm not familiar with the differences in SQLalchemy, so I have to lead you, rather than solving it myself.

Comment: problem is in order_by subquery ").order_by(Like.query.filter(Like.post == UserRecordCard.post_id).count()"
,if you know how to implement subquery in sqlalchemy i'd be grateful,i cant find any good link related to that on google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `.count()` returns an `int` or `long` and not a subquery.

In order to do what you set out to do you would have to do it somewhat like this

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func

obj = (
    UserRecordCard.query
    .filter(
       UserRecordCard.record_card_id == 1,
       UserRecordCard.count == 1
    )
    .order_by(
        select([
            func.count()
        ])
        .select_from(Like.__table__)
        .where(Like.post == UserRecordCard.post_id)
        .correlate(UserRecordCard.__table__)
    )
)
```

The `correlate()` call tells SQLAlchemy to not try to put `UserRecordCard` into the from-clause of the sub-select, but rather take it from the surrounding select.

You may or may not have to use `alias` or `scalar` on the sub-query, I don't remember. The general idea should hold though.

Comment: thanks mate!..that's exactly what i was looking for,it works like charm!